# Como vaciar mi base de datos desde SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

quisiera saber como vaciar mi base datos, desde SQL Server.

Comment: `DROP DATABASE databasename;` ahí lo tienes, ten en cuenta que no solo borra datos, también las tablas, eso si, vacía se quedará.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con vaciar? ¿A eliminarla o a vaciar todo sus contenido (Tablas, Procedimientos almacenados, etc?

Comment: Solo vaciar la Base de datos, SOLO LOS DATOS.. De forma que las tablas y las relaciones entre ellas se conserven.

Comment: La única respuesta medianamente válida es la de Rencinas, pero en este caso el Script de regeneración no lo limitaría solo a las tablas sino a todos los objetos, luego crear un nuevo database y aplicar el Script anterior.

Answer (score 3):

Deberas truncar todas tus tablas.

```
TRUNCATE <<table>> ....
```

[Ayuda comando TRUNCATE](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/truncate.php)

Answer (score 0):

cualquiera de estas debe servir

```
DROP DATABASE nombre; //es para eliminar una base de datos

DROP TABLE nombre; // es para eliminar una tabla

DELETE FROM nombre; //es para eliminar el contenido de una tabla

TRUNCATE TABLE nombre; //es para limpiar totalmente una tabla, el index vuelve a 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo generarte scripts de tablas, borrar la base de datos entera
(`drop database tubasededatos`) y lanzar el backup solo de tablas:

Respuesta original: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14998229/7064040)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]